# triangle containing both numbers and letters in java

Tags: java, numbers, letter

I want to write a Java program that prints a special triangle

Comment: Do you have code that just prints the triangle with a single static character? Because that's what I'd start with, if you don't have that, write that. Then you can add a small code block that picks which character to print each line with.

Comment: No, I have. I am very new on this subject and I am trying to learn.

Comment: I don't understand "No, I have". If you don't have that: write that one first (and google if you have trouble with it, because basically all questions on this topic have already been posted on SO). Then, once you have the basic one-character version, try to adopt it to do what you describe here and ask a **specific** question when you can't get that to work. Right now you're basically asking us to write the whole thing for you.

Answer (score 0):

Printing a triangle like that usually involves a loop with an index counter.

If we write down the counter value, and the [ASCII code](http://www.asciitable.com/) / [Unicode code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Latin_(Unicode_block)) for the characters, we can see a pattern we can use.

```
       1         0: 49
      AAA        1:    65
     33333       2: 51
    CCCCCCC      3:    67
   555555555     4: 53
  EEEEEEEEEEE    5:    69
 7777777777777   6: 55
GGGGGGGGGGGGGGG  7:    71
```

For even values of the index, we can print character with ASCII code `i + 49`, and for odd values we print `i + 64`.

In Java 11+, it can be done as follows. I'll leave it as an exercise for people to fix themselves if they need a solution for versions of Java before 11.

```java
static void printTriangle(int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        System.out.println(" ".repeat(size - i - 1) +
                           Character.toString(i + (i & 1) * 15 + 49).repeat((i << 1) + 1));
    }
}
```

*Output when calling `printTriangle(8)`*

```
       1
      AAA
     33333
    CCCCCCC
   555555555
  EEEEEEEEEEE
 7777777777777
GGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
```

*Output when calling `printTriangle(10)`*

```
         1
        AAA
       33333
      CCCCCCC
     555555555
    EEEEEEEEEEE
   7777777777777
  GGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
 99999999999999999
IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct code:

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    char lastChar = sc.next().charAt(0);   

    int totalLines = lastChar - 'A' + 1;

    for (int i=0; i<totalLines; i++)
    {
        for(int j=1; j<totalLines-i; j++)
            System.out.print(" ");
        
        for (int k=1; k<=2*i+1; k++)
        {
            if (i%2 == 0)
                System.out.print(i+1);
            else
                System.out.print((char)('A'+i-1));
        }
        
        System.out.println();
    }
```